# diffusion equation with boundary $xe^x$

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

I am preparing for the preliminary examination, and I have a question:

Problem B.4 in http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/images/uploads/AM-prelim-201505.pdf

In part (a), doing the direct calculations I have a huge integral from $-\infty$ to $-\infty$ with integrand:
$$\Bigg(\frac{(x-y)^2}{4k^2t^2}-\frac{1}{2kt}+\frac{x-y}{4kt}+1\Bigg)e^{y-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4kt}}y dy$$
which must be zero.

I got stuck here. Any hints on how to continue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier, see that 
$$
\frac{d}{dx} e^{-(x-y)^2 /  4 k t} = \frac{d}{dy} e^{-(x-y)^2 /  4 k t}
$$
So you can use this inside the integral, integrate by parts, and use the fact that the initial condition $ \psi $ satisfies $ \phi_{xx} -  2 \phi_x + \phi = 0 $.

Comment: By the way, it is also possible to do it how you are approaching it. The integral is just a Gaussian integral. After completing the square in the exponential, some of the terms vanish right away from parity. The others take a bit of work, but it is not difficult.